# How do I change the text of a button with jQuery without deleting a span with icons?

Tags: html, jquery

I have this button, shown here as it appears when using Developer Tools on Chrome and doing an inspect:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" data-action-type="2">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok>
    ::before
  </span>
  " Action "
</button>
```

I want to change "Action" to "No Action", so I do this:

```
var btn = $('[data-action-type = "2"]'); 
btn.text('No Action');
```

This *does* change the text, but it also wipes out the span, and thus my icon. How do I change the text while keeping the icon? I tried console.log(btn) to see if I could find where "Action" is and attempt to change just that, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use

```
var btn = $('[data-action-type = "2"]'); 
btn.html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok>::before</span>No Action');
```

Comment: Ah, of course. Haven't used jQuery in a long time. Thanks!

Comment: If the icon is dynamic, it will not work

Answer (score 0):

If you have a static `span` in the `button` tag you can do this
`var button = $('[data-action-type = "2"]');`
`button.html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> ::before </span> Some Text')`
If you have a span but thats not static, what you can do is:
`var button = $('[data-action-type = "2"]');`
`button.contents().last()[0].nodeValue = "Byee"`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the button text in a `span` and bind to it:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){
  const t = $(this);
  const btnTextSpan = t.find('.btn-text')
  t.hasClass('active') ? btnTextSpan.text(t.data('text')) : btnTextSpan.text(t.data('text-active'));
  t.toggleClass('active');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" data-text="Action" data-text-active="No Action">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">✌️</span>
  <span class="btn-text">Action</span>
</button>
```